# "explicit" для конструкторов копирования и перемещения

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

Надо ли (и если да, то в каких случаях) указывать конструкторы копирования и перемещения как `explicit`? Видел такое в коде и не совсем понял. Где ненужное неявное преобразование, которое `explicit` помогает нам избежать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос прост: `explicit` нужен там, где он нужен, а где не нужен — там не нужен. Есть распространённый совет, что все конструкторы, что принимают один аргумент должны быть помечены `explicit`, во избежание случайного создания объектов класса там, где их создание не очевидно. К примеру, есть у нас функция `void someFun(const std::shared_ptr<int[]>&)` и мы, совершенно случайно, используем её так:

```
int* array = new int[55];
someFun(array);
delete[] array;
```

Если бы конструктор `std::shared_ptr` не был `explicit`, то код бы успешно скомпилировался и на третьей строчке мы бы получили неопределённое поведение. Но т.к. конструктор `std::shared_ptr` помечен как `explicit` мы не получим такую ситуацию *случайно*. Таким образом, `explicit` призван исключить случайные ошибки.

Что касается `explicit` конструктора копирования: ни разу не видел такого и не могу придумать, зачем такой может быть нужен. Если мы хотим запретить копирование, то нужно удалить его вообще, если не хотим, то зачем вставлять палки в колёса разрешая лишь узкий набор синтаксических вариантов, используя которые можно будет скопировать объект?

В качестве примера можно привести следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MeClass
{
public:
    MeClass(size_t idx, const string& tag = "") :
        m_Idx{idx},
        m_Tag{tag}
    {    
    }
    MeClass(const MeClass& rhs):
        m_Idx{rhs.m_Idx},
        m_Tag{rhs.m_Tag}
    {
    }
private:
    size_t m_Idx;
    string m_Tag;
};

MeClass explicitReturn()
{
    // Явный вызов конструктора 
    // Неявный вызов конструктора копирования
    // move нужен исключительно для исключения C++17 RVO
    return move(MeClass{2, "meTag"});
}

MeClass implicitReturn()
{
    // Неявный вызов конструктора 
    // Неявный вызов конструктора копирования (до C++17)
    return {3, "meaTag"};
}

void funForFun(const MeClass& me)
{

}

int main()
{
    // Явный вызов конструктора
    MeClass me1{1};
    // Неявный вызов конструктора
    MeClass me2 = 2;
    // Неявный вызов конструктора копирования
    auto me3 = me1;
    // Явный вызов конструктора копирования
    auto me4{me1};
    // Неявный вызов конструктора
    funForFun(2);
    funForFun({3});
    // Явный вызов конструктора
    funForFun(me1);
};
```

Если пометить в коде конструктор как `explicit`, то перестанут работать примеры, где указано явное его использование. То же самое с конструктором копирования.

Answer (score 0):

Ключевое слово explict позволит избежать случайного преобразования типов, которое может привести к неявным ошибкам.

Например: У вас есть класс с конструктором `MyString(int size)`, который создает строку размером size. Также есть метод `print(const MyString&)`, при вызове `print(3)` ты можешь ожидать вызов print("3"), а на самом деле получишь пустую строку из 3 символов.

Хороший и развернутый ответ можно найти [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-mean).

Answer (score 0):

Объявление копирующего конструктора как `explicit` помогает избежать срезки по ошибке, хотя запрещает все передачи параметров текущего типа по значению.
Подробнее об этом написано в книге Саттера и Александреску "Стандарты программирования на C++" под 54 пунктом.

Answer (score -1):

Если у Вас будут в дальнейшем определены или явно удалены операторы копирования и перемещения, то в этом нет никакой обходимости.